# Keybindings are not working in vifm when connecting through ssh

Tags: docker, vifm

I'm connecting to VM via ssh (mRemoteNG) and keybindings doesn't work in vifm file manager.

Example is 'w' for previewing file in another tab.

Same situation is for docker images. I instantiate CentOS7 VM, install vifm and everything is working fine. If I do the same with docker image, it's not working.

Comment: My guess would be that version you have at remote machines is quite old (something like `0.4`). You might need to find a way to install more up to date version.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. I'm using latest version available vifm-0.7.8-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Hm, keys like `w` come from sample `vifmrc`. So you might want to check whether it's installed (see output of `:echo $MYVIFMRC` and look at the file it points to, it should say `Sample ...` near the top). P.S. maybe `$MYVIFMRC` or `$VIFM` from your local machine is passed to VM, which might trick vifm into looking for configuration in wrong place.

Comment: Thanks xaizek, this has helped. Issue is that once vifm is installed as part of container build, vifmrc is not copied anywhere. If I copy one from my host OS, vifm is working fine in container too.

Comment: One more question - I assume that vifmrc is automatically created during install time. Any idea why is this not happening in docker container/image build?

Comment: Might depend on installation procedure. On installation `vifmrc` is placed to `{prefix}/share/vifm/vifmrc` (where prefix is usually `/usr/` or `/usr/local/`). On first start when `~/.vifm/` directory doesn't exist, that file is copied. Maybe `~/.vifm/` is already there in your case or that file isn't installed (maybe try searching for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correct answer in comments.

vifmrc is not copied while creating a container, it has to be done manually posst install. Once it's copied it works just well. Thanks xaizek.